# How to make a Next.js component embeddable?

Tags: widget, next.js13, embeddable

I want to make a specific component of my nextjs 13 website embeddable as widget to other websites without using iframe approach.

I am using Next.js 13 app router. Let's say I have a component  which I want to let users to embed on their website. Inside the page.tsx, there are multiple components but I want specifically this  component to be embeddable.
Are there any npm packages or other approaches available for doing this?

I want something like this:

```
<script>
  window.calendarConfig = {
    userId: "xxxx",
  }
</script>
<script
  src="https://www.mywebsite.com"
  id="xxxx">
</script>
```